# How to disable tabs in Appgyver Supersonic App?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

From example app I am trying to disable tabs. I see that there are tabs array define in structure.coffee but when I empty them make app don't work

```
tabs: [
  {
    title: "Index"
    id: "index"
    location: "example#getting-started" # Supersonic module#view type navigation
  }
  {
    title: "Settings"
    id: "settings"
    location: "example#settings"
  }
  {
    title: "Internet"
    id: "internet"
    location: "http://google.com" # URLs are supported!
  }
]
```

How I can disable them natively without programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the documentation http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/architecture/app-config-files/#structure-coffee

*"If you are not using tabs, you will need to define a root view"*

By default in structure.coffee root view is commented out with # (hash tag). So now you can remove tabs array and define (uncomment) the root view setting with the correct view you want it to show by default.